# rust render newlines as actual newlines with the render literal escape string format in assert eq tests

Tags: rust

I have this assertion error output like this:

```
assertion `left == right` failed
  left: 
r k   nr
p  n ppp
B p p

 P P B
  N    P
 PPK PP
       q
White to move

 right: "\n  kr  nr\np  n ppp\nB p p\n\n P P B\n  N    P\n PPK PP\n       q\nWhite to move\n"
```

as you can see left is rendered as I want newlines as actual newlines,
but right is not the same newlines rendered as \n characters.
How can I make the right render the same as the left showing actual new lines instead of \n characters.

Produced code:

```
fn main() {
    println!("hello world")
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod play_tests {
    
    #[test]
    fn hello() {
        assert_eq!("", r#"
        newline town
        full of lines
        nonsense city
        in the dusty framework
        "#)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3580deb40847fc7d059f9c2abc92c9fa

Comment: This is a bit confusing because your output above doesn't match your code below, and using the code below you can see that the left and right should be handled the same: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f767f6b9834f6f010e7bdc87574d9a46). Can you provide what produced the erroneous output?

Comment: Also see from [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert_eq.html) that `assert_eq!` *"will print the values of the expressions with their debug representations"* i.e. using the `Debug` trait, which for strings will escape control characters like newlines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make assert_eq! in Rust show multiline strings](/q/76243409/2189130)

Comment: Yes it does, but the solutions are too hard to use, the pretty_assertions requires a lot of managing, custom message passed to standard assert_eq, has to be passed in every assert_eq call, please consider providing a simplest answer, that is beautiful.

Comment: I genuinely don't understand how using a library with a macro that does what you want is "a lot of managing". Any other solution (writing a macro yourself, or wrapper type that changes debug output) would be *more* work on your part.

Comment: Well, I can't use the library it clashes with the original assert_eq, it requires to write random garbage everywhere I write a test, very hack-hiss library .

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine for now:

```
struct MLS(String);

impl fmt::Debug for MLS {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    write!(f, "{}", self.0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post this answer to the duplicate I've linked. It solves the same problem in a different way. We prefer not to have competing solutions scattered on different posts.